# Generating a ECDSA Private key in bouncy castle returns a PUBLIC key

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I am attempting to use bouncy castle to generate ECDSA keys. The code seems to work fine from the Java perspective; but, when I dump the file and try to validate the data, OpenSSL does not like the format of the data.

After some research, I figured that bouncy castle is encoding the private key as public key.

Here is my Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        String name = "prime256v1";
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            kpg.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec(name));
            KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();    
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("private.key");
            writer.write(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
            writer.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The file `private.key` is generated in valid DER format; however, when I run the following command to see the ASN.1 structure of the key:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in /my/path/private.key
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 147 cons: SEQUENCE          
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    6:d=1  hl=2 l=  19 cons: SEQUENCE          
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim: OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :prime256v1
   27:d=1  hl=2 l= 121 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: <hex data>
```

For comparison, if I run the following commands to generate a ECDSA key using OpenSSL, I get  the following ASN.1 structure:

```
 $ openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -outform DER -out private.key
 $ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in private.key
     0:d=0  hl=2 l= 119 cons: SEQUENCE          
     2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
     5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: <hex data>
    39:d=1  hl=2 l=  10 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
    41:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :prime256v1
    51:d=1  hl=2 l=  68 cons: cont [ 1 ]        
    53:d=2  hl=2 l=  66 prim: BIT STRING
```

So, I guess my questions are

- Is there anything I am missing?
- Or is this a known bug?
- Is there anyway to get around it?

Comment: "OpenSSL does not like the format of the data." could you elaborate? Does any action fail?

Comment: @jay yes, `$ openssl ec -inform DER -in /my/path/private.key` fails

Comment: There is no bug, it's just that Java outputs PKCS8 format which is not expected by your openssl command.

Comment: That is weird. I tried converting it into .pem format and that is working, which in turn can be converted to a valid DER format(This would be your workaround). `BASE64Encoder b64 = new BASE64Encoder();       String base64pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"+b64.encode(priv.getEncoded())+"\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";           FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("private2.pem");
            writer.write(base64pem.getBytes());
            writer.close();`

Comment: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations

Comment: Interesting!. So, based on your answers, I am able to generate a PKCS8 PEM file from java. Then, I can convert it to a regular style private key (with the `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----` header) by doing `$ openssl ec -in private2.pem -out private.key`

Answer (score -1):

Java outputs key in the encoded format. You should try:

```
private String getPrivateKeyAsHex(PrivateKey privateKey) {

    ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKey) privateKey;
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = new byte[PRIVATE_KEY_LENGTH];
    writeToStream(privateKeyBytes, 0, ecPrivateKey.getS(), PRIVATE_KEY_LENGTH);

    String hex = Hex.toHexString(privateKeyBytes);

    logger.debug("Private key bytes: " + Arrays.toString(privateKeyBytes));
    logger.debug("Private key hex: " + hex);

    return hex;
}

private String getPublicKeyAsHex(PublicKey publicKey) {

    ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) publicKey;
    ECPoint ecPoint = ecPublicKey.getW();

    byte[] publicKeyBytes = new byte[PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH];
    writeToStream(publicKeyBytes, 0, ecPoint.getAffineX(), PRIVATE_KEY_LENGTH);
    writeToStream(publicKeyBytes, PRIVATE_KEY_LENGTH, ecPoint.getAffineY(), PRIVATE_KEY_LENGTH);

    String hex = Hex.toHexString(publicKeyBytes);

    logger.debug("Public key bytes: " + Arrays.toString(publicKeyBytes));
    logger.debug("Public key hex: " + hex);

    return hex;
}

private void writeToStream(byte[] stream, int start, BigInteger value, int size) {
    byte[] data = value.toByteArray();
    int length = Math.min(size, data.length);
    int writeStart = start + size - length;
    int readStart = data.length - length;
    System.arraycopy(data, readStart, stream, writeStart, length);
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know what to do with this. I plugged it into my code and it shows hexadecimal (as expected I suppose), but it can't be parse by openssl.